# Dynamically change a given class in the heritage tree and replace it with another one and initialize it

Tags: python, class, oop, metaclass, method-resolution-order

I am currently working on a library.

I would like to write a wrapper that modifies a class (`Mean` in the example) in the inheritance tree by a new class (suppose `WindowedMean`) and I would like to **initialize** this class (for example **k=10**).

The `Mean` class can be anywhere in the heritage tree this is just one example.

[This link shows the example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fzL81.png)

I know it's not advisable.
Do you have an elegant way to do this?

I imagine using the wrapper like this:

```py
metric = Wrapper(MyClass, k=10)
```

Comment: It's not clear to me what you are trying to accomplish exactly, can you elaborate? What is the desired behavior exactly?

Comment: I have a class that calculates [Accuracy](https://github.com/creme-ml/creme/blob/master/creme/metrics/accuracy.py) incrementally and it inherits from the Mean class.
The role of my wrapper is to change the inheritance of the Accuracy class by replacing [Mean](https://github.com/creme-ml/creme/blob/master/creme/stats/mean.py) with [RollingMean](https://github.com/creme-ml/creme/blob/master/creme/stats/rolling_mean.py). 
These last two classes have exactly the same methods.

This way I could easily calculate the metrics with a rolling window.
Is that clearer for you?

Comment: yes - the last comment actually makes sense. The text of the question, as it is, not so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**update**

Although the solution bellow will work exactly as you described, it came to my attention that with Multiple Inheritance, what you are asking can happen naturally.

Just inherit the class you want to modify, use the normal inheritance mechanisms to override the inherited class behavior. That means, setting a `k=10` class attribute, and hardcoding super-calls to `Mean`'s parent instead of using `super`, if needed.

Then, just create a new  child of `MyClass` and add the overriden child of `Mean` to the inheritance Tree. Note that this sub-class of MyClass does not need a single statement in its body, and will behave exactly like `MyClass`, except for the modified `Mean` now being in the proper place in the mro.

Directly in the interpreter (I had to resort to `exec` to be able to type all the class hierarchy in a single line)

```
In [623]: exec("class GreatGrandParent1: pass\nclass GreatGrandParent2: pass\nclass GrandParent1(GreatGrandParent1, Gre
     ...: atGrandParent2): pass\nclass Mean: pass\nclass Parent1(GrandParent1, Mean): pass\nclass Parent2: pass\nclass 
     ...: MyClass(Parent1, Parent2): pass")                                                                            

In [624]: MyClass.__mro__                                                                                              
Out[624]: 
(__main__.MyClass,
 __main__.Parent1,
 __main__.GrandParent1,
 __main__.GreatGrandParent1,
 __main__.GreatGrandParent2,
 __main__.Mean,
 __main__.Parent2,
 object)

In [625]: class MeanMod(Mean): 
     ...:     k = 10 
     ...:                                                                                                              

In [626]: class MyClassMod(MyClass, MeanMod): pass                                                                     

In [627]: MyClassMod.__mro__                                                                                           
Out[627]: 
(__main__.MyClassMod,
 __main__.MyClass,
 __main__.Parent1,
 __main__.GrandParent1,
 __main__.GreatGrandParent1,
 __main__.GreatGrandParent2,
 __main__.MeanMod,
 __main__.Mean,
 __main__.Parent2,
 object)
```

Note there is a case where that won't work straightforward: if a `super` call in `Mean` was supposed to call a method in `Parent2` in your example. In this case, either resort to the original solution, or use some clever `__mro__` manipulation to skip the method in `Mean`.

**original answer**

It looks like this would work with a class-decorator (which can also be used with this "wrapper" syntax you want).

there are sure cornercases, and things that might go wrong - but if your tree is somewhat well behaved, we have to recursively take *all* the bases on the class you want to wrap, and make the substitution in those bases - we can't simply take the final base, unroll all the ancestor classes in its `__mro__` and just replace the desired class there: the heritage line would be broken bellow it.

That is, let's suppose you have classes `A, B(A), C(B), D(C)`, and you want a clone `D2` of `D`, replacing `B` by `B2(A)` - `D.__bases__` is `C`. `D.__mro__` is `(D, C, B, A, object)` If we try do create a new `D2` forcing the `__mro__` to be
 `(D, C, B2, A, object)` , class `C` would break, as it would not see `B` anymore. (And the code in the previous version of this answer would leave both B and B2 in the inheritance line, leading to further brokerage).
The solution bellow recreates not only a new `B` class but also a new `C`.

Just beware that if `B2` would not itself inherit from `A`, in this same example, `A` itself would be removed from the `__mro__`  for the new, replaced B2 does not need it. If `D` have any functionality that depends on `A`, it will break. This is not easily fixable, but for putting checking mechanisms to ensure the class being replaced contains the same ancestors the replaced class had, and raising an error otherwise - that would be easy to do. But figuring out how to pick and include  the "now gone missing" ancestors is not easy, as it is impossible to know if they are needed at all, just to start.

As for the configuring part, without some example of how your `RollingMean` class is "configured" it is hard to give a proper concrete example - but let's make an subclass of it, updating its dict with the passed parameters - that should do for any configuration needed.

```
from types import new_class

def norm_name(config):
    return "_" + "__".join(f"{key}_{value}" for key, value in config.items())

def ancestor_replace(oldclass: type, newclass: type, config: dict):
    substitutions = {}
    configured_newclass = type(newclass.__name__ + norm_name(config), (newclass,), config)
    def replaced_factory(cls):
        if cls in substitutions:
            return substitutions[cls]
        bases = cls.__bases__
        new_bases = []
        for base in bases:
            if base is oldclass:
                new_bases.append(configured_newclass)
            else:
                new_bases.append(replaced_factory(base))
        if new_bases != bases:
            new_cls = new_class(cls.__name__, tuple(new_bases), exec_body=lambda ns: ns.update(cls.__dict__.copy()))
            substitutions[cls] = new_cls
            return new_cls
        return cls

    return replaced_factory


 # canbe used as:

 #MyNewClass = ancestor_replace(Mean, RollingMean, {"ks": 10})(MyClass)
```

I take some care there to derive the proper metaclass - if no class in your inheritance tree is using a metaclass other than `type`, (usually ABCs or ORM models have differing metaclasses), you could use `type` instead of `types.new_class` in the call.

And finally, an example of using this in the interactive prompt:

```
In [152]: class A: 
     ...:     pass 
     ...:  
     ...: class B(A): 
     ...:     pass 
     ...:  
     ...: class B2(A): 
     ...:     pass 
     ...:  
     ...: class C(B): 
     ...:     pass 
     ...:  
     ...: class D(B): 
     ...:     pass 
     ...:  
     ...: class E(D): 
     ...:     pass 
     ...:                                                                                                                         

In [153]: E2 = ancestor_replace(B, B2, {"k": 20})(E)                                                                              

In [154]: E.__mro__                                                                                                               
Out[154]: (__main__.E, __main__.D, __main__.B, __main__.A, object)

In [155]: E2.__mro__                                                                                                              
Out[155]: 
(__main__.E_modified,
 __main__.D_modified,
 __main__.B2_k_20,
 __main__.B2,
 __main__.A,
 object)

In [156]: E2.k                                                                                                                    
Out[156]: 20
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this?

```
class Parent1(object):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Parent1, self).__init__()

    def speak(self):
        print('Iam parent 1')

class Parent2(object):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Parent2, self).__init__()

    def speak(self):
        print('Iam parent 2')

class Child():
    """docstring for Child."""
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def child_method(self):
        print('child method')

def make_child(inhert):
    child = Child()

    class ChildInhert(Child, inhert):

        def __init__(self):
            inhert.__init__(self)

    return ChildInhert()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    child = make_child(Parent1)
    child.speak()
    child.child_method()
```